# is there a way to filter a product list without the page turning white?

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, filter, product

I created a react product list using state and I also created a filter to filter the product.
My problem is when I clicked on the category button the second time my page disappear.

I tried not to use state to store data in memory but did not work. A link to my sandbox code is here.

https://codesandbox.io/s/l1b3od?file=/src/styles.css&resolutionWidth=612&resolutionHeight=675

Answer (score 0):

You must change you filter function to this:

```
const Filtfunc = (prod)=>{
    const result = Products.filter((x)=>{ // Here's the change
      return x.category === prod
    })
   setData(result)
   console.log(result)
}
```

You were filtering the data not the products, so once it's filtered the first time you have not all the products to filter, only the filtered data.

Comment: well thank you so much it does work . I thought i could use the data stored in state. Another experience added to my small react hat. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

In your `filter` function you try to filter the `Products` by using `data`, but when you click to any category, you set the `data` to be that array with result which can be also empty. You have to filter the array by using `Products`, not the `data` you set later on. Thus, it should be:

```
  const Filtfunc = (prod) => {
    const result = Products.filter((x) => {
      return x.category === prod;
    });
    setData(result);
  };
```

You can also set `if` statement to check if your array returns anything or not:

```
<div className="create">
  {data.length > 0 ? (
    data.map((product) => 
      // things here
    )) : (
  <h2>No result has been found</h2>
)}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it does work! I never imagined this could be the reason for it not to work. Thanks again.